# Display an image above an image for few seconds in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a data widget and each time the widget is clicked the page is refreshed. When I'm offline I want to display a nowifi image above the data image for 3 seconds.

I have  `onerror="wifioff()"` function in the data image.

How can I show the nowifi image for a few seconds above the data image.

Comment: Questions seeking help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html put this somewhere

In your javascript:

var secondstildone=3;
var intervalVariable;

```
function wifioff(){

      $("#errorImg).attr("src", "Images/errorImg.png");

      var f = DoTimerStuff;
      intervalVariable = setInterval(f, 1000);
    }

        DoTimerStuff() { 
            secondstildone--;
            if(secondstildone <= 0){
               $("#errorImg).attr("src", "");
               clearInterval(intervalVariable);
             }

        }
```

Comment: Jquery right ?????

Comment: Yes that's correct, but you could do it with vanilla javascript if you wanted, with some slight changes.